# Using react-hook-form with MUI datePicker

Tags: forms, validation, material-ui, datepicker, react-hook-form

I'm trying to make a form using react-hook-form and mui datePicker like that:

```
<form onSubmit(handleSubmit)>
{...some inputs...}
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
     <DatePicker defaultValue={dayjs(prop.vacation?.startDate)} 
     label="From" {...register("startDate")} /><br/> 
  </LocalizationProvider>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

But when i added the {...register} i got an eeror on the "defaultValue" attribute: "Property 'target' is missing in type 'Dayjs' but required in type '{ target: any; type?: any; }'.ts(2741) form.d.ts(53, 5): 'target' is declared here. usePickerValue.types.d.ts(138, 5): The expected type comes from property 'defaultValue' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DatePickerProps<{ target: any; type?: any; }> & RefAttributes'"

Comment: I have the same issue and simply cannot get this component working with hook forms  Formik works fine but seems quite backwards compared to the older version of the Mui Date pickers.